# FormatMessage returns NULL in lpBuffer

Tags: c, winapi, device-driver

I am calling `SetupCopyOEMInf` to copy a .inf file for a device driver (the MSFT docs say: 'SetupAPI continues to be used for [installing device drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k("setupapi%2FSetupCopyOEMInf");k(SetupCopyOEMInf);k(DevLang-C%2B%2B);k(TargetOS-Windows)&rd=true)').

The call is returning false, so I am then calling `GetLastError` as the docs say (`FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`).  The value returned here is `E000024B` or `3758096971` in decimal.  However, when I call `FormatMessage` [as prescribed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351(v=vs.85).aspx) with the return value from `GetLastError`, `lpBuffer` is NULL.

Also trying to figure out why `SetupCopyOEMInf` would be failing (it seems to work on some .inf files but not others).  This is Windows 8.1

Puzzling...Any ideas out there?

Thanks!

Code:

```
BOOL result = SetupCopyOEMInf(_T("C:\\Users\\edward\\Desktop\\_Test\\cncport.inf"), NULL, SPOST_PATH, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

//result is FALSE

LPVOID lpBuffer;
DWORD dw = GetLastError();

DWORD dwMsg = FormatMessage(
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL,
    dw,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
    (LPTSTR)&lpBuffer,
    2048, NULL);
```

Comment: Perhaps your code is wrong. Since you are keeping that private, I suggest that you will have to debug it yourself.

Comment: What does GetLastError return?

Comment: @David Heffernan: 0xE000024B or 3758096971 in decimal

Comment: That does not look like a system error code. Sorry. That's in the Q. Should not have asked again. Thanks for the code update.

Comment: @David Heffernan:  I know, that's why it is so puzzling.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM` does not support all error codes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/01/8914664.aspx). The one you found is [`ERROR_FILE_HASH_NOT_IN_CATALOG`](http://code.google.com/p/busdog/source/browse/trunk/gFilter/SETUPAPI.H) which is not covered by `FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM`. The `setupapi.h` errors do not appear to have any predefined text for them in a system message resource. You will have to write the error strings yourself.

Comment: How do I know what the error strings are to write them myself?

Comment: This one is "file hash not in catalog."

Answer (score 2):

Even though this post was created a while ago, you actually can get the text by using the HRESULT_FROM_SETUPAPI macro (as posted by Microsoft here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This will map the error code returned to one that can be used in the FormatMessage function.